# Html parsing text from TD Tag

Tags: java, android, android-intent, html-parsing

I have my Html data

```
 <table border='0' cellpadding='3' bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="hostinfo_title2"  width='100%' align="center">
                <tr align='center' bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <td width='26%' class="hostinfo_title3">Archive Url</td>
                </tr>

                <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"
                  <td height="25" align="center">http://www.toradio.com/prgramdetails/20130413_vali_mm.mp3</td>

                </tr>
                              </table>
```

I want to get mp3 url(http://www.toradio.com/prgramdetails/20130413_vali_mm.mp3) from above HTML text.

I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158416/html-text-extraction-in-j2me-without-any-html-tags-and-special-characters),Is it Correct or any better way to parse this text
Could any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's a nice HTML Parser for JAVA.

You should be able to do that with something like this:

```
String html = "<YOUR HTML HERE>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements tds = doc.select("table.hostinfo_title2").select("td");

String mp3Link = "";
for(Element td : tds) {
     if(td.text().contains("mp3") {
         mp3Link = td.text();
         // do something with mp3Link
     }
}
```